# Getting current sentence using Office Javascript API

Tags: javascript, office365

Using the Office Javascript API, I want to be able to select the current sentence in Word.  By current sentence, I mean identifying where the caret position is, then iterating from that position to get the full sentence.

However, looking at the available API calls (such as getSelectedData), this does not seem possible, as there doesn't seem to be a way to get the current caret position.

I know when creating a C# project, you could use 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range' and 'Selection.Range' to get a range, which you could use as a caret position.

Am I wrong or can you not get the caret position using the Javascript API?

Answer (score 1):

Late but maybe still helpful for someone:

You can achieve this by combining `getSelection()` and `getTextRanges([separators])`on a document - this expands the current selection in both directions, until any of the characters in the list of separators is found.

Documentation for `getTextRanges`: https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/range

Example (typescript):

```js
Word.run(context => {
  let sentences = context.document.getSelection().getTextRanges(['\n', '.', '?'], false);
  context.load(sentences);
  context.sync().then(() => {
    console.log(sentences.items);
  }
  return context.sync();
}
```

Comment: And to get the sentence to the currrent cursor position?